# Disable date after 7 days from today using datePicker4.4

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using **datePicker v4.4**.

I've trouble in **disabling present date & dates after 7days** from today.

Below is the link for part of my work.

please help.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1K1jV5hEUiMMDA3VmxZM2tBWUk/preview?pli=1

Comment: Please post the **relevant** code here in your post. **Not the entire project**

Comment: I am not posting my entire project. it's just html page with plugin of date picker. it's a Java scripts plugin implemented in html. so you need to download the file. Please check it out

Comment: I cant open google drive from my work place please post code here

Comment: @gillesc I tried that but whenever I am making any modification the calendar itself get disable

Comment: Every documentation says I need to modify the plugin. that code is of 1200 + line

Comment: Ha just looked at your link it's not the jQuery date picker anyway bit's DatePicker v4.4 by frequency-decoder.com

Comment: I'll recommend using jQuery UI date picker seen as you're using jQuery already, the API is dead simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum selectable date. When set to null, there is no maximum.
Multiple types supported:

**Date:** A date object containing the maximum date.

**Number:** A number of days from today. For example 2 represents two days from today and -1 represents yesterday.

**String:** A string in the format defined by the dateFormat option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are "y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, and "d" for days. For example, "+1m +7d" represents one month and seven days from today.

```
 $( ".selector" ).datepicker({ maxDate: "+1m +1w" });

    // getter
var maxDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate" );
// setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", "+1m +1w" );
```

For FROM DATE you use **mindate** like below

```
 var minDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate" );
// setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) );
```

Hope this helps...